# Generate consecutive sentence of int values accessed from different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to generate a sequence of `int` values: `{ 0, 1, 2, ... }`, but there's a twist: I need to access them from different threads.

So I wrote this code:

```
class Counter
{
    private static Counter instance = new Counter();
    private static int i = 0;

    public static Counter Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public int Next()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            return i++;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

May this be implemented in a simpler way?

Comment: Your code looks quite simple, readable and obvious to me (ignoring the unnecessary singleton “noise”). Why do you want to do it even simpler?

Comment: @svick also I expect that probably `lock` can be avoided somehow, probably c# has built-in `synchronized int` or something?

Comment: @javapowered, yes, C# has something like that, but it's quite hard to get right. So, unless this code is a performance bottleneck for you, you should probably stick with `lock`.

Comment: I think [Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static int i = 0;
```

Are you sure that `i` should be static? If it's static there isn't too much sense of the `Counter instance = new Counter()` instance and the `Next` and the `Reset` methods also could be static.

Anyway, I'd use a longer variable name, like `nextValue` for better readability.

Furthermore, consider the drawbacks of the Singleton pattern:

> This pattern makes unit testing far more difficult, 
>   as it introduces global state into an application.

More on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Drawbacks).

Answer (score 0):

Never lock on `this` as your callers can also do the same and cause deadlocks where you don't expect them. See below where I create and use a `private` locking variable. And made `i` an instance variable since you use a singleton instance anyhow.

```
class Counter
{
    private static readonly Counter instance = new Counter();

    private static readonly object locker = new object();

    private int i;

    public static Counter Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public int Next()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            return i++;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't look simpler, I know that it is not recomended to lock on `this` but it's fine for such small simple and rarely used class imho.

Comment: Never claimed it was simpler -- just making it work properly. That's the first step before trying to simplify.

Comment: Nitpicking: `lock (locker)` makes me think of a box that contains a secret that one locks. I would call it something else ... maybe lockHandle, like Bill Wagner does http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1231461

Comment: Hm.. I can buy that `locker` isn't a good name, but I really detest things with `handle` in them when they're not actually handles, either. `lockingObject`, `monitor` (since `lock` expands to `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`), `sync` ??